# Javascript click() don't work on Mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I must use a proprietary software for the project. In this software there is part that generates mobile surveys. In the mobile survey mode i have access only to the css... no html, no javascript.

However i find out that i can run javascript from `<a href="javascript:CODE">`, executes on click on that element.

I need to create custom button that acts like the forward button, but do some other stuff as well.

The code that i'm using is:

```
<a id="theNavButtons" href="javascript:document.getElementById('q1_1_content').parentNode.getElementsByTagName('a')[4].click()" > >>> </a>
```

If I test this using alert and changing .click() with .innerHTML I see that I get the correct element (the forward button on the page). I also tested .click() on some other elements and it is working, but for this element it is not.

Here is a demo link, it is in mobile mode, click forward once to see the second page:
http://author.euro.confirmit.com/extwix/extquicktest_p1839573894.aspx?__qtkey=c2c45e09c13b427b925611227091e3cd&l=29&__rm=2

I tried exploring the events connected to the forwadbutton, but there is too much custom code there...

Please give me some ideas...

Comment: Your code didn't come through for some reason.

Comment: Thanks it is corrected now, sorry i'm new here.

Comment: What are you trying to fix? It appears to work as a forward button?

Comment: Hi Evan, i'm trying to make the anchor element >>> (at the bottom of the page) to work as forward button, not the present forward button itself.

Comment: The one that seems to disappear after a couple of seconds?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't disappear, try search >>> on the page. Thanks for looking into this man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out on my own.

The thing is that the system was wrapping everything in a form element.

Using document.forms[0].submit() on the a element did the trick :)

Have a nice day,
Rado